# SQL 2005 how to set hasdbaccess

Tags: sql-server-2005

In MS-SQL 2005 when i exec

**select * from sys.sysusers**

in **master** database , guest user **hasdbaccess** = 1 .

how to set hasdbaccess = 0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose it's not as simple as:

```
update sys.sysusers
    set hasdbaccess = 0
    where user = 'guest'
```

or something similar? No, life is never that easy :-)

You would normally use `deny` or `revoke` to remove such permissions but be aware that guest is not considered a regular user. For some reason, `GUEST` is not subject to `REVOKE CONNECT` on the master or tempdb databases.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189438.aspx) for that little statement of fact but not much explanation as to why.

On further investigation, some people seem to suggest that it's required on the master DB because that's where the user (login) information is stored. So, during login, everyone accesses that DB with the guest account since their 'real' account and permissions are  not yet known.

Because the guest account is used for all users without validated credentials (and that's everyone up until the point where their login succeeds), that makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

```
REVOKE CONNECT TO [username]
```

will be equal to that query